# Import python module in Azure Machine Learning

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook, python-import, azure-machine-learning-service

I am facing some issues when I try to import my own python module in Azure Machine Learning notebook.

Specifically, I have coded my python file "test.py" with a method called "test_method()" like this:

```
def test_method():
    print("Hello world")
```

In the notebook of Azure Machine Learning I would like to do something like this:

```
from test import test_method
test_method()
```

But the error I get is "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test'. I have everything in the same path and if I am doing the same on Jupyter Notebook locally it works correctly.

What should I do?

Comment: provide the details of folder structure you have?

Comment: Try restart the kernel and run the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the function in my `.py` file.

```
def print_h():
    print("Hello world")
    
def subd(a,b):
    print("sub: a - b = "+ str(a-b))
    
def get_add(a,b):
    print("a + b = "+str(a+b))
```

I imported this module in notebook and i got output successfully.

[image]

Then I created  `test.py` file  and added below code.

```
def greet(name):
    print("Welcome "+name)
```

Know i imported `test` and ran.
Got same output what you got.

[image]

Then i restarted the kernal and executed. It worked.

[image]

Output:

[image]